# Qual a pronúncia específica de "duplex" ou "triplex"?

Tags: pronúncia

No Brasil usa-se os termos *duplex* e *triplex* para se referenciar um apartamento de 2 ou 3 andares, respectivamente. Recentemente estas palavras tiveram um grande destaque na mídia, mas era comum ver repórteres pronunciando *dúplex* (ou *tríplex*) enquanto outros falavam *duplex* e *triplex*.

Estranhamente o Priberam apresenta as 2 pronúncias para [*duplex*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Duplex) com o significado de apartamento de 2 andares. Já o Michaelis possui entradas para [*dúplex*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/duplex%20_948703.html) e [*duplex*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/duplex%20_948704.html) e em nenhuma cita o significado de apartamento duplo.

Comment: Em Portugal, ouvi sempre como oxítonas.

Comment: Idem, idem, aspas, aspas, mas parece que o original é *dúplex*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basicamente a pronúncia original é *dúplex* e *tríplex*, e o pessoal a certa altura mudou para *duplex* e *triplex*. Eis o que diz o Dicionário Houaiss da Língua Portuguesa (com algumas das abreviaturas desabreviadas por mim):

> **duplex** forma não preferida e mais usual que *DÚPLEX* (‘construção’) ●  USO o emprego consagrou a forma oxítona com 2 números
>
> **dúplex** **1** *numeral multiplicativo (adj.2g.)* multiplicado por dois; dúplice ▪ *adj.2g.2n.s.m.2n.* [...] **4** que ou o que se construiu com dois pavimentos <*casa dúplex*> <*comprou um dúplex de frente para o mar*> → forma não preferida e mais usual: *duplex* **5** LITURGIA CATÓLICA relativo a ou o cerimonial a que corresponde, na missa e no ofício divino, uma música própria tradicionalmente conservada no canto gregoriano [...] ● USO o emprego consagrou a forma oxítona com 2 números (o plural culto seria *dúplices*, jamais empregue no sentido de ‘apartamento dúplex’, ‘casa duplex’)

Ora o que acontece é que *dúplex* é uma palavra antiga: antes de se aplicar a apartamentos já tinha outros significados, nomeadamente o 5 do Houaiss. O [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/d%C3%BAplex) expande este significado e indica também *convento dúplex*, que tem religiosos dos dois sexos, e cita Almeida Garrett em *As viagens na Minha Terra*  (um granda pincel que eu tive que ler na escola) na sua edição de 1883 (ênfase minha):

> A milagrosa Santa Iria ― Santa Irene ― que deu o seu nome a Santarém, donzela nobre, natural da antiga Nabância, e freira no ***convento dúplex*** beneditino que pastoreava o santo abade Célio, floreceu pelos meados do sétimo século.

A história é basicamente a mesma para *tríplex* e *triplex*. Nomeadamente o Houaiss tem exatamente as mesmas notas relativamente ao uso.

No Google Books, as primeiras referências a apartamentos *duplex* aparecem nos anos sessenta; e é sempre *duplex* e não *dúplex*. E este padrão, nos outros significados da palavra, já vem pelo menos dos anos quarenta. Antes, não dá para ver: encontro *duplex* e não *dúplex*, mas em textos que também têm *ordinario, seculo*, etc.― ainda não se usavam sistematicamente, no Brasil especialmente, acentos para indicar a sílaba tónica. Depois, é já na presente década que se começa frequentemente a ver *dúplex*. Há no entanto alguns exemplos anteriores. O primeiro que encontrei é de 1984, na revista brasileira [*Visão* nº 36-44, p. 50:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=X645AQAAIAAJ&q=d%C3%BAplex%20n%C3%A3o&dq=d%C3%BAplex%20n%C3%A3o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYhbSu0KLMAhVBVRoKHZemBTk4ChDoAQg2MAM)
[image]

Face à existência destas duas formas, cada dicionário adotou a sua estratégia. O Houaiss tem também na entrada *dúplex* os significados que aparecem em [*duplex* no Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/duplex%20_948704.html). Se digitares *duplex* no Aulete, aparece-te imediatamente *dúplex*; A [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/duplex) tem *duplex*, mas manda-te ver *dúplex*; e o Priberam, menos sentencioso, simplesmente apresenta as duas formas, sem as explicações do Houaiss.

Portanto, estás à vontade para usar a forma mais consagrada pelo uso popular ou a forma original. Neste último caso poderás depois ter de dar explicações.

Comment: Interessante que o Aulete menciona _(Bras.) Diz-se dos apartamentos de dois pavimentos. [Pronuncia-se erroneamente como oxítono.]), dando a entender que a forma correta seria a paroxítona, provavelmente tendo como razão o uso anterior da palavra. BTW (aliás, existe um equivalente em português para _BTW (By The Way)_?), fazia tempo que não ouvia _pincel_ nessa acepção_ que usaste.

Comment: É, o Aulete é coerente com o Houaiss. Foi até pelo Aulete que eu comecei. Citei o Houaiss por ser mais completo quanto à evolução da palavra. Também prefiro a expressão menos contundente *não preferida* do Houaiss ao *erróneo* do Aulete. Dizer que *duplex* é erróneo baseia-se em critérios históricos, que muita boa gente não aceita. Quanto ao *BTW* → *Ask Question*

Comment: @gmauch Adicionei mais informação: a forma *duplex* já vem pelo menos dos anos 40, e houve e esse ressurgimento de *dúplex* que tu notaste também transparece no Google Books.